Loop not terminating and the execution keeps going
I am trying to write a code where there are three gates and each gate can take 3,4,5 visitors respectively.
there is a global count and local count and race conditions are allowed. But the loop is not terminating.

int global_counter = 0;

proctype EntranceGate(int gate_id; int visitors) {
    int i = 0;          
    int local_counter;   
    do
    :: (i < visitors) -> 
        local_counter = global_counter;       
        local_counter = local_counter + 1;    
        global_counter = local_counter;       
        
        printf("Gate %d: Incremented to %d\n", gate_id, global_counter);
        
        i = i + 1
    :: else -> break 
    od;
}


init {
    
    run EntranceGate(1, 3); 
    run EntranceGate(2, 4); 
    run EntranceGate(3, 5); 

    
    do
    :: (global_counter == 12) -> break 
    :: (global_counter > 12) -> 
        printf("ERROR: Global counter exceeded the limit!\n");
        break 
    :: else -> skip 
    od;

    
    printf("Final global counter: %d\n", global_counter);
}

I tried using gate and max visitors as array, but that is also not working.
